# to one-hot encode parts of my string data

Tags: string, bioinformatics, one-hot-encoding

> ACN58946.1|FEATURES|NCBI|macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin|macB|antibiotic target protection|0\sMAEPVLSVKDLDIRFTTPDGNVHAVKKVSFDIAPGECLGVVGESGSGKSQLFMACIGLLAGNGKATGSVTYRGQELLGQPAAKLNAIRGAKITMIFQDPLTSLTPHMRIGDQIVESLRTHSKLSKGEAEKRAIQALELVRIPEAKRRMRQYPHELSGGMRQRVMIAMATACGPDLLIADEPTTALDVTVQAQILDIMRDLRKELGTSIALISHDMGVIASICDRVQVMRYGEFVETGPADDIFYHPQHPYTRMLLEAMPRIDQPVREGRAALKPLAPQEARTTLLEVDNVKVHFPIQMGGVFFGKYKPLRAVDGVSFTLHQGETIGIVGESGCGKSTLARAVLELLPKTTGGVVWMGRDLGALPPAELRRARKDFQIVFQDPLASLDPRMTIGQSIAEPLQSLEPELSKHEVQSRVRAIMEKVGLDPDWINRYPHEFSGGQNQRVGIARAMILKPKLIVCDEAVSALDVSIQAQIVDLILSLQAEFGMSIIFISHDLSVVRQVSHRVMVLYLGRVVELASRDAIYEDARHPYTKALISAVTVPDPRAERLKKRRELPGELPSPLDTRSALMFLKSKRIDDPDAEQYVPKLIEVAPGHFVAEHDPFEVVEMTG\e>ACN58871.1|FEATURES|NCBI|macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin|macB|antibiotic efflux|0\sMADYLLEMKNIVKEFGGVRALNGIDIKLKAGECAGLCGENGAGKSTLMKVLSAVYPHGTWDGEILWDGKPLRAQSIRETEAAGIVIIHQELMLVPELSVAENIFLGNEIKLPGGRMDYAAMNRRAEELLAELDIRDVNVVLPVKQYGGGYQQLIEIAKALNKNARLLILDEPSSSLTASEIKVLLRIIHSLKAKGVTCVYISHKLDEVADICDTIVVIRDGQHIATTPMADMNIERIIAQMVGREMNQLYPERSHVPGEVIFEARNVSCYDADNPQRKRVDNISFKLRKGEILGIAGLVGAGRTELVSALFGAYPGPSEAEVWLNGVKLDTRTPLKAIRAGLAMVPEDRKQHGIVPDLGVGHNMTLAVLNDFVRATRIDQQAELATIHKEIKSVKLKTATPFLPITSLSGGNQQKAVLSKMLLTKPKILILDEPTRGVDVGAKFEIYQLMFDLAAQGMSIIMVSSELAEVLGISDRVLVVGEGKLRGDFVNDNLSQETVLAAALDHTQPALH\e>ACN58991.1|FEATURES|NCBI|multidrug|cmeB|antibiotic efflux|0\sMKNDRGEMVPFSAFMTIKKKQGANEINRYNMYNTAAIRGGPATGYSSGEAIKAVQEVAAKNLPNGFDIDWAALSYDETRRGNEAVYIFLIVLAFVYLVLAAQYESFIIPLAVVFSLPAGVFGSFLLIKGMGLANDIYAQVGLVMLVGLLGKNAVLIVEFAVQKQQQGATVFEAAIEGARVRFRPILMTSFAFIAGLIPLVFAHGAGAIGNKTIGSSALGGMFFGTVFGVIVVPGLYYVFGSWAEGRKLIRGEDHDPLTENLVHQMDNFPQSDDK\e>ACN58776.1|FEATURES|NCBI|macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin|macA|antibiotic efflux|0\sMGNLPRPTLSPSLSGIRPTMNRETTTRVDSSTPAARLGMRVPSTSRAALVGVAALVVILGGWYGIKRWRAHVASEGQYIFAAIQKGDIEDLVTATGSLQPRDYVDVGAQVSGQLDKILVEVGSDVKEGDLLAEIDADVAAARVDASRAQLRSQQAQLVQQQANLTKAERDLTRQQNLMKEDATTAEQVQNAETTLDTTKAQINALKAQMEQLRASMRVDESNLNYTKILAPMSGTVVSISAKQGQTLNTNQQAPTILRIADLSTMTVQTQVSEADVSKLRSGMQAYFTTLGSAGKRWYGQLKKIEPTPTVTNNVVLYNALFEVPNDNKQLLPQMTAQVFFVAAAAHDVLVVPMSAVSLQRTPPGGIPNAAAAQAAGARGAGAQGAGAQGAQGASAQGAGAQSGQGGQGAAALTPEQIARREARRQQRMQSNGGSATGGAIEGGPPRGGFGASMAARGPRHATVRVQAADGKIEERQITIGVTNRVHAEVLSGLKEGERVVAGTKEPEKAPATAGGQQGAGGQRNNIGGFPGGGLGGGFGR\e

I am working with protein sequences right now. I have these string data which parts I want to convert to one-hot encode. The parts that I want to convert starts after '\s' and end before '\e', then I want to do it for the whole string data. Since the I have thousands of datasets, using pure Python code seems impossible, since it will take a long time to finish the process. Is there any machine learning library for this problem?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [SKLearn's one-hot encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). It should encode your data with maximum efficiency.

If you're looking to optimize other ML tasks in Python, I suggest checking out [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/)/[Keras](https://keras.io/), [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) [scikit-learn (SKLearn)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/), and [ScyPi](https://scipy.org/). Of course, [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) is also essential. These tools are powerful, heavily optimized, and have lots of resources out there to help you out. They should get you through almost any ML problem you run into :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) for this.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
    
data = "ACN58946.1|FEATURES|NCBI|macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin|macB|antibiotic target protection|0\sMAEPVLSVKDLDIRFTTPDGNVHAVKKVSFDIAPGECLGVVGESGSGKSQLFMACIGLLAGNGKATGSVTYRGQELLGQPAAKLNAIRGAKITMIFQDPLTSLTPHMRIGDQIVESLRTHSKLSKGEAEKRAIQALELVRIPEAKRRMRQYPHELSGGMRQRVMIAMATACGPDLLIADEPTTALDVTVQAQILDIMRDLRKELGTSIALISHDMGVIASICDRVQVMRYGEFVETGPADDIFYHPQHPYTRMLLEAMPRIDQPVREGRAALKPLAPQEARTTLLEVDNVKVHFPIQMGGVFFGKYKPLRAVDGVSFTLHQGETIGIVGESGCGKSTLARAVLELLPKTTGGVVWMGRDLGALPPAELRRARKDFQIVFQDPLASLDPRMTIGQSIAEPLQSLEPELSKHEVQSRVRAIMEKVGLDPDWINRYPHEFSGGQNQRVGIARAMILKPKLIVCDEAVSALDVSIQAQIVDLILSLQAEFGMSIIFISHDLSVVRQVSHRVMVLYLGRVVELASRDAIYEDARHPYTKALISAVTVPDPRAERLKKRRELPGELPSPLDTRSALMFLKSKRIDDPDAEQYVPKLIEVAPGHFVAEHDPFEVVEMTG\e>ACN58871.1|FEATURES|NCBI|macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin|macB|antibiotic efflux|0\sMADYLLEMKNIVKEFGGVRALNGIDIKLKAGECAGLCGENGAGKSTLMKVLSAVYPHGTWDGEILWDGKPLRAQSIRETEAAGIVIIHQELMLVPELSVAENIFLGNEIKLPGGRMDYAAMNRRAEELLAELDIRDVNVVLPVKQYGGGYQQLIEIAKALNKNARLLILDEPSSSLTASEIKVLLRIIHSLKAKGVTCVYISHKLDEVADICDTIVVIRDGQHIATTPMADMNIERIIAQMVGREMNQLYPERSHVPGEVIFEARNVSCYDADNPQRKRVDNISFKLRKGEILGIAGLVGAGRTELVSALFGAYPGPSEAEVWLNGVKLDTRTPLKAIRAGLAMVPEDRKQHGIVPDLGVGHNMTLAVLNDFVRATRIDQQAELATIHKEIKSVKLKTATPFLPITSLSGGNQQKAVLSKMLLTKPKILILDEPTRGVDVGAKFEIYQLMFDLAAQGMSIIMVSSELAEVLGISDRVLVVGEGKLRGDFVNDNLSQETVLAAALDHTQPALH\e>ACN58991.1|FEATURES|NCBI|multidrug|cmeB|antibiotic efflux|0\sMKNDRGEMVPFSAFMTIKKKQGANEINRYNMYNTAAIRGGPATGYSSGEAIKAVQEVAAKNLPNGFDIDWAALSYDETRRGNEAVYIFLIVLAFVYLVLAAQYESFIIPLAVVFSLPAGVFGSFLLIKGMGLANDIYAQVGLVMLVGLLGKNAVLIVEFAVQKQQQGATVFEAAIEGARVRFRPILMTSFAFIAGLIPLVFAHGAGAIGNKTIGSSALGGMFFGTVFGVIVVPGLYYVFGSWAEGRKLIRGEDHDPLTENLVHQMDNFPQSDDK\e>ACN58776.1|FEATURES|NCBI|macrolide-lincosamide-streptogramin|macA|antibiotic efflux|0\sMGNLPRPTLSPSLSGIRPTMNRETTTRVDSSTPAARLGMRVPSTSRAALVGVAALVVILGGWYGIKRWRAHVASEGQYIFAAIQKGDIEDLVTATGSLQPRDYVDVGAQVSGQLDKILVEVGSDVKEGDLLAEIDADVAAARVDASRAQLRSQQAQLVQQQANLTKAERDLTRQQNLMKEDATTAEQVQNAETTLDTTKAQINALKAQMEQLRASMRVDESNLNYTKILAPMSGTVVSISAKQGQTLNTNQQAPTILRIADLSTMTVQTQVSEADVSKLRSGMQAYFTTLGSAGKRWYGQLKKIEPTPTVTNNVVLYNALFEVPNDNKQLLPQMTAQVFFVAAAAHDVLVVPMSAVSLQRTPPGGIPNAAAAQAAGARGAGAQGAGAQGAQGASAQGAGAQSGQGGQGAAALTPEQIARREARRQQRMQSNGGSATGGAIEGGPPRGGFGASMAARGPRHATVRVQAADGKIEERQITIGVTNRVHAEVLSGLKEGERVVAGTKEPEKAPATAGGQQGAGGQRNNIGGFPGGGLGGGFGR\e"
data = data.replace('\e>', '\r')
with io.BytesIO(data.encode('utf8')) as binary_file:
    with io.TextIOWrapper(binary_file, encoding='utf8') as file_obj:
        df = pd.read_table(file_obj, sep="|", header=None, )
df[6] = df[6].str.replace('0\s', '', regex=False)
```

Gets you a Dataframe like this:
[image]

Afterwards you can use [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)
or [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to encode your protein sequences. I show the pandas version here:

```py
df = pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=[6])
```

This is an example, if your data is available in a variable. If its a textfile, the io methods are not needed and should be replaced by loading the txt file. Also be aware that *"\e>"* should be replaced by an newline character e.g. *"\r"* or *"\n"* to get the samples seperated.

Comment: mine is a textfile actually, but i have no idea on how to convert it directly into one-hot encoding, since this is my first time working with textfile. in this task i need to use the protein sequences as the input and the others as the output of the classification. could you let me know how you'd do it?